# How would I assign an event-listener to a div that allows the width and height of the div to grow 20% when clicked

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, dom-events, event-listener

I have begun to write it out and I used the same size (100px by 100px) as I used in a previous question. I'm trying to use only Javascript for now although I plan on using jQuery some time in the future. The main problem I see now is that on the line (`this.style.width`) 'this' is not yet defined so the code does not know that 'this' refers to the div and I am unsure how this would be done using an event listener rather than `childNodes` (which I know how to do).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head lang="en">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <style>
    div {background-color: #999999;width: 100px;height: 100px;}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv" onClick="handleClick(event)"></div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

/**
* Created by Mark M.G on 4/1/2015.
* n221
*/


function handleClick(event){

this.style.width = ( parseInt( this.style.width ) *1.2 ) + 'px';
this.style.height = ( parseInt( this.style.height ) *1.2 ) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: the event object usually contains the event target, which you can extract and use instead of 'this'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pure JS working solution based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/oco94wrs/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {background-color: #999999;width: 100px;height: 100px;}
```

Javascript:

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
div.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   this.style.width = ( parseInt( this.offsetWidth ) *1.2 ) + 'px';
   this.style.height = ( parseInt( this.offsetHeight ) *1.2 ) + 'px';
});
```

Now, the `this` is referring to the actual div because I assigned the click event listener directly to the div. 
On your code, the `this` was referring to the window object because it was in a global function.

Another possible solution could be to use event.target.

Comment: I do plan on using jquery in the future I'm just trying to learn as much as I can about JavaScript for now.

Comment: I just edited my answer to try to explain why <code>this</code> was referring to different objects in the code you provided and the one I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `this` instead of `event` in your `onClick` event, and use a different parameter name in the event handler like '`element`' to avoid confusion. :) Then replace `this` in the event handler with the parameter name ('`element`') to access the clicked element in the event handler.